# Skip pattern at start of string

Tags: kotlin

I want to skip text at the start of a string in Kotlin like the Java `Scanner.skip()`

please tell me how to do something like `string.skip("**")` to skip `**` at the start of `string`
for example `"**hello stack".skip("**") --> "hello stack"`

Comment: Do you need to match against regex or just String?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I didn't realize you wanted it at the *start* only, just use `removePrefix`:

```
"**hello stack".removePrefix("**") // "hello stack"
```

> If this char sequence starts with the given prefix, returns a new char sequence with the prefix removed. Otherwise, returns a new char sequence with the same characters.
>   <sub>[kotlin.text.removePrefix](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/remove-prefix.html)</sub>

---

> I want to skip text at the start of a string

You can use `substringAfter`:

```
"**hello stack".substringAfter("**") // "hello stack"
```

> Returns a substring after the first occurrence of `delimiter`. If the string does not contain the delimiter, returns `missingDelimiterValue` which defaults to the original string.
>   <sub>[kotlin.text.substringAfter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-after.html)</sub>

When the given delimiter is not present, `substringAfter` will simply return `missingDelimiterValue`, which by default is the original string:

```
"foo".substringAfter("**") // "foo"
"foo".substringAfter("**", "no match") // "no match"
```

Comment: this is wrong cos `"hello**stack".substringAfter("**") --> "stack"` ..... it should only check for the "**" at the beginning

Comment: @JoeQstc You're right, I didn't see that requirement. Edited. Kotlin has a function for that as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var data = "**hi dhl**"

    println(data.removePrefix("**")) //  hi dhl**
    println(data.removeSuffix("**")) //  **hi dhl
    println(data.removeSurrounding("**")) // hi dhl

    println(data.substringAfter("**")) // hi dhl**
    println(data.substringAfter("--")) // **hi dhl**
    println(data.substringAfter("--","no match")) // no match

    data = "{JAVA | KOTLIN | C++ | PYTHON}"
    println(data.removeSurrounding("{", "}")) // JAVA | KOTLIN | C++ | PYTHON
```

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin is fully designed with interoperability in mind. You can use all Java classes including Scanner.

What you would like to achieve is creation extenstion function

This is just unefficient draft. But you can optimize for your need.

```
fun String.skip(pattern: String): String {
   val scanner = Scanner(this)
    //scanner opeations
   return scanner.nextLine()
}
```

Take a look here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html & 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html